# How do i get a total amount of the people where my Bot is in?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so i haven't been coding for quite a long time and when i was reading the Discord.js Guide, i didn't saw how i can get the total amount of Users where my Bot is in.
Because apparently since V13/V14 `client.users.cache.size` is not working because the Bot Logs only 1 Person.

I have currently this in my Upgraded Bot Version (from djs V12).

```
client.once("ready", () => {

//console.log('The Blax Beta is online! ')

console.log(`I'm currently on ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers with ${client.users.cache.size} people.`)

const activities = [
    `with ${client.users.cache.size} people.`,
    "music.",
    "with my Owner.",
    ` | Version ${client.BotVersion}`,
    `on ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers.`,
    `/help`
];

setInterval(() => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1));
    const newActivity = activities[randomIndex];

    client.user.setActivity(newActivity);
}, 10000);

client.user.setActivity(` | Version ${client.BotVersion}`)
});
```

Thanks to whoever can help me.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I have currently all Intents activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Before I start, double check to make sure you have the GuildMembers intent enabled - in the Discord Developers dashboard AND in your code.*

As you figured out, client.users.cache doesn't actually cache all users your bot is in a guild with (you can imagine how large that object would be for a bot like dank memer).

One way to calculate this is by going through each of the guilds your bot is in and using the guild's `memberCount` property, which is just a plain integer with the number of users. Unfortunately, since it's just a number, you can't filter out bots from `memberCount`. If you're fine with that then this code should do the trick:

```
const guilds = client.guilds.cache;
var totalUsers = 0;

guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    totalUsers += guild.memberCount;
});

console.log(totalUsers);
```

---

However, if you don't want to include bots in the user count (I like to do this because my bots are in a lot of Discord bot listing website guilds, so there are thousands of bots that my bot is in the same guild with) you can do a similar thing but fetch all the members in each guild.

But, even if your bot is only in a few dozen servers, it can still take a very long time to fetch that many users, so I like using an array of promises and the `Promise.all` function to do this.

Example:

```
const guilds = client.guilds.cache;
const promiseArr = [];

guilds.forEach(guild => {
    // push a promise that resolves with the number of members in the server
    promiseArr.push(new Promise(async (resolve, _reject) => {
        // fetches the members in the guild
        var members = await guild.members.fetch();
        members = members.filter(m => !m.user.bot);
        resolve(members.size);
    }));
});

// calls every promise and returns them into an array
var results = await Promise.all(promiseArr);
// this function takes all the numbers in the array and adds them into a single number
var totalUsers = results.reduce((prevVal, currVal) => prevVal + currVal);
console.log(totalUsers);
```

Comment: I tried placing it into my Code, not just Copy paste lol, but it shows me this:
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Yes, you need to make the function that is using this code async. e.g. `client.on("ready", async () => { <code here> })`